# How to get all the account details using Get-MailBox 

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, asp.net-3.5, exchange-server

I know this is silly question but I am new with Powershell cmdlet.

I want all details of user of a mailbox. I am using `Get-MailBox` but I just get Alias name and name there, but I want all the details. I can't find any parameter for that even. Is there any way??Thank You

Comment: What other details are you wanting?

Comment: I want First Name ,Last Name and almost all the properties.Because we create email address with help of first name and last name so I cant change only email address with different first name and last name.I hope You can understand this .Thank You.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're new to [PowerShell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/dd742419) I suggest you look at some of the resources [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/windows-powershell-survival-guide.aspx). Apart from that you probably want to use `Get-Member`, `Select-Object` and/or `Format-List`. Perhaps doing something like:

```
PS> Get-MailBox | Get-Member
```

a load of properties and methods will be scrolling by you can select the properties you wish to see using something like

```
PS> Get-MailBox | Select-Object Alias
```

To get all available information you could use `Format-List` with the `*` glob like so:

```
PS> Get-MailBox | Format-List *
```

I don't have acces to an Exchange environment so I can't provide any specific examples I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks For great help,Its working great with Powershell.Now I get all details with that command .Now I am looking for appropriate code in C# .As Format-List is not parameter I am confuse how to code it with C#.

Comment: This Is the solution                                     Command cmdSetMailbox = new Command("Get-MailBox");
            cmdSetMailbox.Parameters.Add("Identity", txtName.Text);
            Command cmd = new Command("Select-Object");
            string[] Parameter = new string[] {"Alias","DisplayName"};
            cmd.Parameters.Add("Property",Parameter);

Answer (score -1):

The data you want to store/retrieve might be in Active directory.  Exchange is pretty much used for exchange specific functionality

I'm using Server 2012 R2 and use the following code because I'm lazy.  Copy the whole command together so ignore the word wrapping on this site.  I'm posting this here because I always forget what I did and keep coming here on random searches.

Launch a Powershell Window as administrator on a Domain Controller

```
Get-ADUser -F * -PR * | Select 
Name,Title,Enabled,LockedOut,OfficePhone,MobilePhone,Fax,office,EmployeeID,Company | Out-GridView
```

Also here are some random useful Exchange commands so you can compare.
To see what information is available for a user, just pull everything.
From the Exchange server logged on as a user with permissions..

Launch Exchange Powershell

```
Get-Mailbox | Format-List *
```

Gives everything for every user under the sun.  Limit it with the following.

```
Get-Mailbox %useralias% | Format-List *
```

If the fields you want aren't here, then it is most likely stored in active directory.

Comment: Out-GridView opened an new powershell window for every object. This could crash your server with RAM usage if the list is long enough.